# CSS Clouds - How to adjust to inner content?

Tags: css

I have a fiddle that I created here that explains what I am trying to do exactly:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9THqX/3/)

Basically, I need to have text inside of the cloud and adjust the outside borders (that are using box-shadow effects) according to what is in the inside.  Figured this is possible with just CSS, but perhaps it is not?

Can anyone provide an example or start for doing this?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cloud1"></div>
        <div class="cloud2"></div>
    <div class="cloud3"></div>
        <div class="cloud4"></div>
        <div class="cloud5"></div>
        <div class="cloud6"></div>
    <div class="cloud7"></div>
    <div class="cloud8"></div>
    <div class="inner">This is a CSS Cloud and is looking super cool, but need to figure out how to adjust the outside borders of the cloud so that they wrap around this text no matter how much text is in here.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.cloud1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 15px;
    height:45px;
     width:90px;
    background: whitesmoke;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 0px -1px 2px -2px black;
    border-bottom: none;
    z-index: 9;
}
.cloud2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 15px;
    height: 45px;
    width:80px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 80px 80px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 80px 80px 0 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 16px -4px white, 0px -1px 2px -1px black;
    z-index: 6;
}

.cloud3 {
     position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 45px;
     height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius:  0 90px 90px 0;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 2px 0 4px -3px black;
    z-index: 7;
}
.cloud4 {
     position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 120px;
     height:60px;
     width:30px;
     border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius:  0 60px 60px 0;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 1px 0 4px -2px black;
    z-index: 8;
}
.cloud5 {
    position: absolute;
    left:55px;
    top: 165px;
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 16px -4px white, 0px 1px 2px -2px black;
    z-index: 8;
}
.cloud6 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 165px;
     height:30px;
     width:60px;
     border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 16px -4px white, 0px 2px 2px -2px black;
    z-index: 7;
}
.cloud7 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 80px;
    height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, -1px 0 4px -2px black;
     background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 8;
}
.cloud8 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: 35px;
    height:60px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
     -moz-border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, -1px 0 4px -2px black;
     background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 7;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 135px;
    height: 90px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 60px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

So thinking if I put a `min-height` on the elements instead of using `height` that this would do the trick, but it doesn't :(

Comment: cool idea, but all the borders and shadows are set in pixels. You would need a section that can repeat. I would say use a background image, but I don't think that is your goal

Comment: Well, here it is set in `em` units:  http://jsfiddle.net/9THqX/6/  if that makes a difference...

Comment: True, The goal is to do this without an image!

Comment: How much do you want them to be able to expand?

Comment: I only ask because sooner or later with the width being limited, it won't look like a cloud.

Comment: for a start, I think you should remove all absolute positioning if you need the cloud elements to adjust according to the content

Comment: @Danield Wow, ok, so removed all absolute positioning, changing to relative, and here's what I have now:  http://jsfiddle.net/9THqX/7/ sooo close to what I need... OMG, it's like right on the tip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove all absolute positioning. (as I mentioned in the comments)

Next place the whitesmoke background on the title element instead of it's parent element (which has padding) and you get a pretty good result.

```
.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: whitesmoke; /* here */
}
```

You can experiment with adding pseudo elements around the title to add circles around the top-left and bottom right areas of the text.

```
.title:before {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, -1px 0 4px -2px black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: whitesmoke;
    top:0;
}
.title:after {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 1px 0 4px -2px black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: whitesmoke;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9THqX/11/)** (I updated the fiddle you posted in the comments)

Comment: Ok, this is extremely close to what I need for sure!  We are definitely on the right track now!  So +1 for your answer... BUT, as you can see, while the text is now within the cloud, the bubble outlines are now screwed up... so am thinking we need more bubbles or a way for more bubbles to appear as it gets stretched in height... hmmmmm

Comment: I updated the fiddle - try experimenting with the values to get an effect which is good for your needs

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update... trying to get rid of the white space below and the crazy black line above (top-left), but having difficulty with this... arggg!  This is definitely the best I could hope for I suppose!

Comment: Just going to mark this as my answer and thank you very much, will settle for this instead:  http://jsfiddle.net/9THqX/12/ Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9THqX/4/)

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.cloud1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 15px;
    height:45px;
     width:90px;
    background: whitesmoke;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 0px -1px 2px -2px black;
    border-bottom: none;
    z-index: 9;
}
.cloud2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 15px;
    height: 45px;
    width:110px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 80px 80px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 80px 80px 0 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 16px -4px white, 0px -1px 2px -1px black;
    z-index: 6;
}

.cloud3 {
     position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 45px;
     height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius:  0 90px 90px 0;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 2px 0 4px -3px black;
    z-index: 7;
}
.cloud4 {
     position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
    top: 120px;
     height:90px;
     width:30px;
     border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 60px 60px 0;
     -webkit-border-radius:  0 60px 60px 0;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, 1px 0 4px -2px black;
    z-index: 8;
}
.cloud5 {
    position: absolute;
    left:55px;
    top: 165px;
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 16px -4px white, 0px 1px 2px -2px black;
    z-index: 8;
}
.cloud6 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 170px;
     height:30px;
     width:60px;
     border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
     background: whitesmoke;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 16px -4px white, 0px 2px 2px -2px black;
    z-index: 7;
}
.cloud7 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 80px;
    height:90px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, -1px 0 4px -2px black;
     background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 8;
}
.cloud8 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: 35px;
    height:80px;
     width:45px;
     border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
     -moz-border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 60px 0 0 60px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 16px -4px white, -1px 0 4px -2px black;
     background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 7;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    left: 5px;
    top: 40px;
    background: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I have tried and did my best.

Comment: Not sure what you changed, but if I add more text so the `<div class="inner">` element, it doesn't wrap around it at all...

Comment: I have just changed `width`, `height` and other elements

Comment: Well, it doesn't change anything, and makes the cloud look terrible.  So, I'm guessing that this isn't possible in CSS than?  I guess the `border-radius` properties would also need to change, but don't think you can put a `min` value on any of the `border-radius` properties.  But than again, `em` units might suffice for this instead.

Comment: But than, even still, how do we get the inside (`div class="inner"`) to adjust the height of the clouds?